# Meaning of 'be bond to' in "since ye are bond to that magic" in 19th-century poem

Tags: etymology, ambiguity, poetry

I am reading a poem by Rudyard Kipling, Kitchener's School (http://www.kiplingsociety.co.uk/poems_kitchener.htm) and I am wondering about the precise meaning/possible connotations of the verb 'be bond to' in the last line of the penultimate stanza, which goes:

> Certainly they were mad from of old; but I think one new thing,
>   That the magic whereby they work their magic — wherefrom their fortunes spring —
>   May be that they show all peoples their magic and ask no price in return.
>   Wherefore, since ye are bond to that magic, O Hubshee, make haste and learn!"

("Hubshee" is a derogatory term essentially meaning 'negroe')

I am wondering if this is just a (19th century?) variation on 'bound'? Then of course 'spell-bound' comes to mind. I can't overstate the importance of this word for the interpretation of this poem. Especially in terms of the level of inevitability, if that makes sense. Being spell-bound is very different from being bound as if by ropes by someone, or be bound for a destination, for example.. But perhaps it was always already meant to be overdetermined.

Grateful for any thoughts!
cheers,
alina

Comment: An alternate form of _bound_, just as _ye_ is an alternate form of _you_. This is poetry.

Answer (score 2):

As you suggest (and as @JohnLawler has confirmed), *bond* could be just an older form of *bound* — but *bound* in the sense of "tied to" (but not literally tied).

I believe that *in bond* was also used to describe the relationship of a slave/servant to his master, where, for example, the master had some 'hold' over the slave/servant.  Such a 'hold' could arise because the master provided shelter/housing for the slave/servant; or paid for their schooling; or had bought the slave/servant for a set number of years; etc..  In such circumstances, I think the slave/servant was said to be *in bond* to the master for a period of years, effectively until the 'debt' (e.g. the cost of the schooling) had been paid for by their servitude.  Thus the servant was *bound* (tied) to the master for that period.

I've read through the whole poem (from your link) and this interpretation *could* fit — but I'm not certain that that is the meaning.

[Dictionary definitions](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bond) also support both the above meanings of *bond*:

- (bonds) Ropes, chains, or other restraints used to hold someone prisoner:
- An agreement with legal force, in particular: ... A deed by which a person is committed to make payment to another.

Additionally, the above meaning of *in bond* also still exists in the sense of dutiable goods being held *[in bond](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/in-bond?q=in+bond)*, i.e. stored in a bonded warehouse, until the importer pays the duty owing.

Answer (score 1):

"Hubshee" has a more specific meaning than what you're suggesting, and it refers to an Abyssinian(Hubshee)/Ethiopian, which I believe is important for the interpretation given the date of the poem.   The Ethiopian Empire's "independence" at the time probably felt more like forestalled occupation given that [almost all of Africa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scramble_for_Africa) was being dramatically swept up by European powers, and Kipling seems to be warning Ethiopia to tread lightly.  While they're independent, Kipling still warns them, "[C]arry your shoes in your hand and bow your head on your breast (to school)."

The Ethiopians seemed bound by duty, for the sake of self preservation, to learn the English ways at Kitchener's "madrissa," which is Arabic for "school."  The "magic" that they were bound to was essentially the English madness, which could easily become tyranny, according to Kipling.

Answer (score 0):

To *bond in* could mean to relate with or to have a perfect understanding or to agree with.

Thus, "Since ye are bond to that magic" could mean that you have a perfect understanding of the magic OR a connection to it.

**bond** \ *ˈbänd* \ *noun* : something (such as an idea, interest, experience, or feeling) that is shared between people or groups and forms a connection between them. From Merriam Webster dictionary.

Comment: "Since ye are bond to that magic". It could mean yo have a perfect understanding of the magic OR a connection

Comment: bond\ˈbänd\
noun
: something (such as an idea, interest, experience, or feeling) that is shared between people or groups and forms a connection between them. From Merriam Webster doctionary.

Comment: Thanks.  I've taken the liberty of amending your answer to include your comments, and have deleted my earlier comments.  I've also removed my downvote.